# R group by one column and apply custom function to another column

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, anonymous-function

Say I have a data frame like this:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)), Data = rep(1:5, 3))
```

How do I apply this function to the second (numerical) column by each group A, B and C?:

```
Percent <- function(x){(x/length(x))*100}
```

So the result is like this:

```
x Data
 A 20
 A 40
 A 60
 A 80
 A 100
 B 20
 B 40
 ...etc
```

I have tried `aggregate()` and various methods in `dplyr` but either a) the code wants to apply the function to both columns, resulting in an error or b) it applies it to the `Data` column but doesn't preserve the data frame so I just get back a vector (or list of vectors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
fun <- function(x) {
 (x/n()) * 100
}

x %>%
 group_by(x) %>%
 mutate(Data = fun(Data))

   x      Data
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 A        20
 2 A        40
 3 A        60
 4 A        80
 5 A       100
 6 B        20
 7 B        40
 8 B        60
 9 B        80
10 B       100
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

**Code**

```
setDT(dt)

dt = data.table(x); percent = function(x){100*x/length(x)}
dt[, Percent := percent(Data), keyby=x]
```

**Result**

```
> dt
    x Data Percent
 1: A    1      20
 2: A    2      40
 3: A    3      60
 4: A    4      80
 5: A    5     100
 6: B    1      20
 7: B    2      40
 8: B    3      60
 9: B    4      80
10: B    5     100
11: C    1      20
12: C    2      40
13: C    3      60
14: C    4      80
15: C    5     100
```